# SK learn, Python

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to make a regression that is determined by the operator XOR. I created a training set:

[image: training set]

Then I created a test set:

[image: test set]

I use this code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

data_train = np.loadtxt('1.csv', delimiter=';')
data_test = np.loadtxt('2.csv', delimiter=';')
X = data_train[:, 1:]
y = data_train[:, 0].astype(np.int)
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
expected = y
predicted = model.predict(X)
#print(metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted))
#print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
print(model.predict_proba(data_test))
```

But I have this warning :

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
```

And this error:

`ValueError: X has 3 features per sample; expecting 2`

But I have just 2.
If I did wrong, tell :). I'm new at this

Comment: start by printing `X` to make sure it is as you think it is...

Comment: X : [[ 0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]] Y:
[0 0 1 1]

Comment: Give a [mcve] please

Comment: error is not thrown from the code provided, it is thrown by `precision` calculation. Nothing in your code would case it to even run. Valueu error, on the other hand comes from the fact that your `test_data` has 3 features, and should have 2.